# react-pdf from ByteArray response?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-pdf

I am trying to request a PDF file from my java server through a react typescript app.  Then trying to display this byte[] through react-pdf.

The request to the server looks like this:

```
const [invoice, setInvoice] = React.useState<any>()   

 const downloadPdf = (theInvoice: Invoice) => {
        store.app.cubaRest?.invokeService<any>('billing_InvoiceService', 'generateInvoiceDocument', { invoice: theInvoice })
            .then((response: any) => {
                console.log(response)
                let array= JSON.parse(response).content
                setInvoice(array)             
            }).finally(()=>{                
            })    
        }
```

---

```
 if (invoice) {
        console.log("there is invoice")
        return (
            <div>
                <Document
                    file={{ data: invoice }}
                    onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
                    onLoadError={console.error}
                >
                    <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
                </Document>
            </div>
```

The console log from the raw "response" above looks like this:

```
{"report":{"_entityName":"report$Report","id":"1dd6746f-3580-6e3c-3aa6-e3f5db0a290b","code":"default-invoice","roles":[],"defaultTemplate":{"id":"0de287de-1931-a375-d10f-70ae431a3ca7","content":"PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPCEtLSBDcmVhdGVkIHdpdGggSmFzcGVyc29mdCBTdHVkaW8gdmVyc2lvbiA2LjE2LjAuZmluYWwgdXNpbmcgSmFzcGVyUmVwb3J0cyBMaWJyYXJ5IHZlcnNpb24gNi4xNi4wLTQ4NTc5ZDkwOWI3OTQzYjY0NjkwYzY1YzcxZTA3ZTBiODA5ODE5MjggIC0tPgo8amFzcGVyUmVwb3J0IHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vamFzcGVycmVwb3J0cy5zb3VyY2Vmb3JnZS5uZXQvamFzcGVycmVwb3J0cyIgeG1sbnM6eHNpPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxL1hNTFNjaGVtYS1pbnN0YW5jZSIgeHNpOnNjaGVtYUxvY2F0aW9uPSJodHRwOi8vamFzcGVycmVwb3J0cy5z .......
```

When I set the state from the response the page just keeps rerendering and the pdf does not show.  Presumably it is doing a re-render for every byte in the byte array.

Not sure how to resolve this.   Also not sure if I am sending the byte[] correctly to setInvoice either.  Or if the byteArray is in the correct format for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Was quite a simple solution.

instead of:

```
let array= JSON.parse(response).content
            setInvoice(array)
```

do:

```
setInvoice({data: JSON.parse(response).content});
```

---

```
 if (invoice) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Document
                file={invoice}
                onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
                onLoadError={console.error}
            >
                <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
            </Document>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres the base64 approach

**1. Given base64 string of the pdf file**

```
const fileAsBase64 = || YOUR PDF FILE IN BASE64 AS STRING ||
```

**2. Convert base64 string to bytearray**

```
export const base64ToArrayBuffer = (base64) => {
const binaryString = window.atob(base64); // Comment this if not using base64
const bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryString.length);
return bytes.map((byte, i) => binaryString.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

**3. Add the byearray to component by calling above function**

```
 <Document file={{ data :base64ToArrayBuffer(base64)}}/>
```